# Have text wrap at a certain width if it can without breaking a word

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have an element which will contain dynamic text, that I would prefer to be 30% of its container, but wouldn't mind it stretching if the content won't allow due to long words.

If I have inline-block width 30% at certain times some of the text will overflow the container, and looks bad.

If I have inline-block width auto, the text never overflows, but the container grows as long as the text without breaking at all.

I'd like some way of having a "wrap at width" of 30%, so text begins wrapping there, but if it can't wrap the container just stretches big to be enough.

I'd love a 100% CSS answer if it can be done. I have a few ideas on how I'd do it in Javascript, but I want to avoid that if possible.

I have messed around with display:table-cell but that screwed up my layout because I need this to be 100% height, and tables don't respect that.

Problem illustrated here:
http://codepen.io/nicklepedde/pen/gLYgpw

html:

```
<div class="con">
  <div class="side">
  Sometimes this text is long
  </div>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.con{position:relative;width:600px;background:orange}
.side{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
  filter:opacity(.8);
  font-size:50px
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The font size, or actual text used is not under my control, please do not take my example too literally. I know that the word is too big, it's the point of me asking here. And no, I can't just change the font size, that's not an option in the problem I'm trying to solve.

I updated my codepen to more closely simulate my final product:
http://codepen.io/nicklepedde/pen/gLYgpw

Comment: Have you tried CSS word-wrap? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: Title: "Have text wrap at a certain width if it can **without breaking a word**".

Comment: Okay now looking at the updates I understand better, I have deleted my previous answer so I can answer the proper question. My question for you is this, you say you can't control font size or content, can you list what else cannot be changed or is out of your control. Thanks

Comment: Well point is, I just want the div to be no more than 30% unless it would break a word, or cause it to bleed. I had mild success with dsplay table-cell, but the height was never 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can just float the elements left and set the widths at the percentages you'd like. Just make sure to set a global box-sizing:border-box so your elements don't move down the page if you set margins and padding.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.con{
  /*position:relative;*/
  float:left;
  width:70%;
  /*width:600px;*/
  background:orange;
    padding:4px;
}
.side{
  /*position:absolute;
    left:0;
  top:0;*/
  padding:4px;
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  height:100vh;
  background:yellow;
  filter:opacity(.8);
  font-size:50px /* for only 30% width, I would consider decreasing the font size */
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  Sometimes this text is long
  </div>
<div class="con">
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
   <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
  <p>This is filled with other content that sets the height some what dynamically</p>
</div>
```

Here's my edit to your code, hope it helps.

http://codepen.io/ciammarino/pen/dObNQO

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however the "side" div is meant to be an overlay on top of the other div. In practice it's an image with text overlaid I just threw dummy content because what's behind the div is't the point.

Comment: Is the side div 30% of the page or 30% of the containing div with the width of 600px?

Comment: Ahh! I understand. There are WCAG2 compliance factors to consider as far as the text being overlaid on an image. This is something you may be able to take to your stakeholders